# DynamoDB Pagination

Tags: java, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing pagination in DynamoDb and see that the result not like my expected, but I still don't know where wrong in my code. 
I have searched for this document and see that I just need to set evaluated key which I got last evaluated key from last request to pass to next request.
Here is my code :

```
public QueryResultPage<SbmBookingInfo> getListBooking(String email, int size,
        String lastTimeStamp, String lastBookingId, boolean isForward) {
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(getClient());
    Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
    expressionAttributeValues.put(":email", new AttributeValue().withS(email));
    if (lastBookingId == null) {
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<SbmBookingInfo> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<SbmBookingInfo>()
                .withIndexName("practitioner-index").withKeyConditionExpression("email=:email")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues).withConsistentRead(false).withLimit(size);
        QueryResultPage<SbmBookingInfo> result = mapper.queryPage(SbmBookingInfo.class, queryExpression);
        m_log.info("Last evaluated key " + result.getLastEvaluatedKey());
        return result;
    } else {
        Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = new HashMap<>();
        lastEvaluatedKey.put("timeStamp", new AttributeValue().withN(lastTimeStamp));
        lastEvaluatedKey.put("bookingId", new AttributeValue().withN(lastBookingId));
        lastEvaluatedKey.put("email", new AttributeValue().withS(email));
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<SbmBookingInfo> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<SbmBookingInfo>().withLimit(size)
                .withIndexName("practitioner-index").withKeyConditionExpression("email=:email")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues).withConsistentRead(false)
                .withScanIndexForward(isForward).withExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);
        m_log.info("Exclusive key" + queryExpression.getExclusiveStartKey());
        return mapper.queryPage(SbmBookingInfo.class, queryExpression);

    }

}
```

- This table has three key: bookingId is hashkey, index: email, and timeStamp is rangeKey.
- I checked this function by making the first request and I receive last evaluated key then I make second request with passing the info that I received but seem like it didn't work.
- Please help me at this case. Thanks